# Permanent permit

Tags: united-kingdom

I am a wife of a EU . My 5 years card will expire in a month. Do I have to apply for resident card or am allowed permanent resident  and which website should I get the application from.  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to apply for resident card?

No.  See [Apply for a UK residence card/Permanent residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/permanent-residence-card):

> [Y]ou do not need a permanent residence card to confirm your residence status in the UK unless:
>
> - you’re an extended family member of someone from the European Economic Area or Switzerland and are yourself not an EEA or Swiss national
> - you want to apply for British citizenship
> - you want to sponsor your partner’s visa application under the Immigration Rules

The first and last points do not apply to you, but the second point might.  If it does not, however, you might prefer wait until next March when you will be able to apply for [settled status](https://www.gov.uk/settled-status-eu-citizens-families) instead.

On the other hand, having a permanent resident card might make your life easier, for example if you need to be able to prove your right to work in the UK or if you travel outside the UK and want to be able to return easily.

The current plan is for residence cards to remain valid until December 31, 2020; settled status will be valid indefinitely.  The window for settled status applications will be between March 2019 and 30 June 2021.

> [W]hich website should I get the application from?

There is a link at [Apply for a UK residence card/Apply](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/apply) pointing you to an online application that you can use only if your spouse includes you in an application for a permanent residence card.  Otherwise, you can download the paper application form from that page.